# PHP Calculating dates for every Thursday and Sunday for X weeks

Tags: php, datetime

I have written a round robin tournament generator in PHP for an online electronic sports league, and I need to calculate the dates for each game in the tournament. Games are played every Thursday and Sunday over the course of many weeks (the number of weeks is dependent on how many teams are participating). **Given the starting week and the number of weeks what would be the best way to calculate those dates?**

I'm guessing it requires using some combination of DateTime, DateInterval, and DatePeriod; but I am having trouble figuring out how it would be done.

**Update:**
Apologies for not providing the code before. Here is the solution I had originally come up with. I didn't know if there was a simpler way of doing it. The function was called submitSchedule where the dates were generated.

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

function roundRobin($teams) {
    $len = count($teams);
    $schedule = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $len - 1; $i++)
    {
        $home = array_slice($teams, 0, $len / 2);
        $away = array_slice($teams, $len / 2);
        $day = array();

        for ($j = 0; $j < $len / 2; $j++)
        {
            array_push($day, array($home[$j], $away[$j]));
        }

        array_push($schedule, $day);

        $temp = $away[0];

        for ($j = 0; $j < count($away) - 1; $j++)
        {
            $away[$j] = $away[$j + 1];
        }

        $away[count($away) - 1] = $home[count($home) - 1];

        for ($j = count($home) - 1; $j > 1; $j--)
        {
            $home[$j] = $home[$j - 1];
        }

        $home[1] = $temp;

        $teams = array_merge($home, $away);
    }

    return $schedule;
}

function roundRobinBalanced($teams)
{
    $schedule = roundRobin($teams);

    for ($i = 1; $i < count($schedule); $i+=2)
    {
        $schedule[$i][0] = array_reverse($schedule[$i][0]);
    }

    return $schedule;
}

function doubleRoundRobinBalanced($teams)
{
    $sched2 = roundRobinBalanced($teams);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($sched2); $i++)
    {
        $sched2[$i] = array_reverse($sched2[$i]);
    }
    return array_merge(roundRobinBalanced($teams), $sched2);
}

function tripleRoundRobinBalanced($teams)
{
    return array_merge(doubleRoundRobinBalanced($teams), roundRobinBalanced($teams));
}

function submitSchedule($schedule, $start, $intervals, &$con)
{
    mysqli_query($con, "TRUNCATE TABLE matches");
    $curDate = $start;
    echo "<pre>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($schedule); $i++)
    {
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($schedule[$i]); $j++)
        {
            $temp0 = $schedule[$i][$j][0];
            $temp1 = $schedule[$i][$j][1];
            $temp2 = date_format($curDate, "Y-m-d");
            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO matches (T1ID, T2ID, gameDate) VALUES ('$temp0', '$temp1', '$temp2')");
            echo "<span style=\"background:lightblue;\">( " . date_format(new DateTime(), "Y-m-d H:i:s") . " )</span>" . "> INSERT INTO matches (T1ID, T2ID, gameDate) VALUES (". $schedule[$i][$j][0] . ", " . $schedule[$i][$j][1] . ", \"" . date_format($curDate, "Y-m-d") . "\")<br>";
        }

        date_add($curDate, date_interval_create_from_date_string($intervals[$i % count($intervals)]));
    }
    echo "</pre>";
}

$teams = array();

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","root","REMOVED","schedule");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

//Select all items from the 'teams' table and order them first in descending order by points, then in ascending order by 'teamName'
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM teams");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    array_push($teams, $row['TID']);
}

if (count($teams) % 2 == 1)
{
    array_push($teams, null);
}
shuffle($teams);

$schedule = tripleRoundRobinBalanced($teams);

// echo "<pre>" . json_encode($schedule, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) . "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($schedule);
echo "</pre>";

// ---- List of possible DateTime expressions ----
// thursday
// next thursday
// YYYY-MM-DD
// DD/MM/yy
// thursday + 1 day

$start = new DateTime("thursday"); // Indicates the date of the first game
$jump = array("3 days", "4 days"); // Indicates the time intervals of each game (e.g. If day 1 starts on thursday, day 2 starts on sunday, day 3 starts on thursday, etc.)

submitSchedule($schedule, $start, $jump, $con);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A good way could be using `DateTime`, `DateInterval` and a loop. Read up on the docs.

Comment: @kingkero Apologies, I forgot to include the code that I wrote so far. I am away from the computer where I stored the PHP files, so as soon as I get home, I will add them.

Answer (score 1):

The way to achieve this is by using PHP's DateTime classes as you guessed. They are really very useful. I would suggest a little function something like this:-

```
/**
 * @param $startWeek ISO week number of the first week
 * @param $numWeeks  The number of weeks to run including the first
 *
 * @return \DateTime[] An array of DateTime objects
 */
function getPlayDays($startWeek, $numWeeks)
{
    $numWeeks --;
    $result = [];
    $currYear = (int)(new \DateTime())->format('Y');
    $oneDay = new \DateInterval('P1D');
    // Start on the first Thursday of the given week.
    $startDate = (new \DateTime())->setISODate($currYear, $startWeek, 4);

    $endDate = clone $startDate;
    $endDate->add(new \DateInterval("P{$numWeeks}W"));

    // End on the Sunday of the last week.
    $endDate->setISODate((int)$endDate->format('o'), (int)$endDate->format('W'), 7);

    $period = new \DatePeriod($startDate, $oneDay, $endDate->add($oneDay));

    foreach($period as $day){
        if(4 === (int)$day->format('N') || 7 === (int)$day->format('N') ){
            $result[] = $day;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

foreach(getPlayDays(1, 3) as $playDay){
    var_dump($playDay->format('D m-d-Y'));
}
```

You didn't specify how you would identify the starting week, so I have assumed an ISO week number.

Output:-

```
string 'Thu 01-02-2014' (length=14)
string 'Sun 01-05-2014' (length=14)
string 'Thu 01-09-2014' (length=14)
string 'Sun 01-12-2014' (length=14)
string 'Thu 01-16-2014' (length=14)
string 'Sun 01-19-2014' (length=14)
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/P9VHA).

[DateTime manual](http://php.net/datetime).

This function will quite happily cope with DST changes, leap years and weeks close to the start and end of the year thanks to the built in magic of the DateTime classes :)

[proof or STFU](http://3v4l.org/Dbto9).

Comment: That's a very clever way of doing it. I will check that out. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what day of the week does PHP consider to be the first day? Sunday or Monday?

Comment: From the manual:- `"N ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week (added in PHP 5.1.0) 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)"`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the strtotime function:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

You could do something like this:

```
$startDate = "May 15, 2014";
$startDate = strtotime($startDate);
```

And you could get the start of the Sunday match by simply adding three days:

```
$nextDate = strtotime("+3 day", $startDate);
```

Your question is a bit vague, but I think this is what you were asking.

Comment: `DateTime()` is much better suited for this.

Comment: I'm certain that almost anything other than strtotime would be better suited for this. The only reason I used the example is because it's very easy to understand. :)

Comment: I realize now that my question was vague without the code I had written. I have written a solution to my problem, but the current method I am employing is not very "user friendly." I will post the code once I get home.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have the timestamps of the day of starting week (06:00 AM time)...
Every other date will be 7 days (86400 seconds * 7) in the future.

Let's assume you will run this for 52 weeks (1 year)

```
$firstThu = 1234567890;
$firstSun = 9876543210;

$nextThus = array();
$nextSuns = array();

for($i=0; $i<52; $i++) {
    $nextThus[] = date('d/m/Y', $firstThu + (86400 * 7 * $i));
    $nextSuns[] = date('d/m/Y', $firstSun + (86400 * 7 * $i));
}
```

At the end of the loop you will have two arrays with all the 52 weeks dates.